# How can I use OAuth2/OpenIdConnect to implement "acting on behalf of"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

Is it just me that feels the OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect standards are pretty fuzzy on "acting on behalf" functionality.

I have the following scenario, I would outline the OAuth2 Stakeholders as follows:

- **Resource Owner:** User with Username/Password
- **Application:** MVC Website .NET Core v2.1
- **Resource Server:** WebAPI .NET Core v2.1
- **Authorization Server:** Auth0
- **User Agent:** Web Browser

Seems like typical Authorization Code flow, there are many examples around about how to do this for .NET Core v2.0.
The trickiest bit is using the `OpenIdConnectEvents.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event to request an Access Token from the code.

Assuming I get the Access Token it will give me any Claims I need to determine the authorization of the Web Site e.g.
Render menu options but only if they are allowed to make the requests and use the Authorize attribute to protect endpoints.

My question is, I have an API which provides some service to many Services User one of which is my MVC Website. 
I want to make a request from my MVC Website to this API. I can request an Access Token using the Client Credentials flow passing Client Credentials agreed for my MVC Website.

If however, I'd like that Access Token to reflect the permissions of my User (who logged into my MVC App with Username/Password) I can't see how to do this. I have an Identity Token for them (so I know they are who they say they are). I have a `sub` claim which uniquely identifies who they are in my Access Token that I got via the Authorization Code flow.

Why can I not make the Client Credentials *"/oauth/token"* request to my Authorization Server passing that `sub` and receive an Access Token to my API with the Claims for my User and not my Application.

It feels like it is sort of Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant but I don't want to go back to the User and say "Can you give me permission to talk to my own internal API, that you know nothing about, on your behalf". I mean if it was to talk to Google/Facebook et al of course but it isn't.

There is the `azp` Authorized party, maybe that could be used to store the identifier of my MVC Site? While the `sub` was the User in the Access Token?

At the moment the only solution I have is to give Authorization Claims for the API back in the Access Token to the MVC App. It just seems Auth Service needs to know what APIs my MVC App will call.

Can anyone make any suggestions? I'd be very appreciative.